# php facebook sdk issue multiple database

Tags: php

I'm using php facebook sdk on my website I have two subfolders each has a different database but after facebook auth it redirects to the main url of the site and does not save the data to the correct database. The data should be submitted to header("Location: https://123.com/uae/user/fblogin"); but insteaded it is redirected to header("Location: https://123.com/user/fblogin");

```
// graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?locale=en_US&fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
            $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name');
            $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email'); // To Get Facebook full name
            $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
            $first_name = $graphObject->getProperty('first_name');    // To Get Facebook email ID
            $last_name = $graphObject->getProperty('last_name');    // To Get Facebook email ID

    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/

        $_SESSION['FB']['fbid'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FB']['fullname'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['FB']['email'] =  $femail;
        $_SESSION['FB']['first_name'] =  $first_name;
        $_SESSION['FB']['last_name'] =  $last_name;

            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION);die;
            if(isset($_SESSION['connect']) && $_SESSION['connect'] == 1){

                unset($_SESSION['connect']);
                   header("Location: https://123.com/uae/fbconnect/");
            }else{
                header("Location: https://123.com/uae/user/fblogin");
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the code you're using so we can help you further. Also check [How to ask in order to obtain a satisfactory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands, this question is not answerable.

Comment: this is the code for getting data from fb sdk but the redirect disregards the /uae